# Prove that $\sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Define the set $cA=\lbrace ca | a\in A\rbrace$.
Prove that $\sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $s_1=\sup(cA)$ and $s_2=\sup(A)$. Then, if $b_1$ is any upper bound to the set $cA$, $b_1\geq s_1\geq ca$ for any $a\in A$. If $b_2$ is any upper bound to the set $A$, then $b_2\geq s_2\geq a$ for any $a\in A$.

I'm not too sure what to do after this. What I would like to do is something like $\frac{s_1}{c}\geq a$ for any $a\in A$, so $\frac{s_1}{c}=s_2$ so $\sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$, but I don't think it's this simple.

**Edit**
Here is my second attempt:

Let $s=\sup(A)$. Then, if $b$ is any upper bound of the set $A$, $b\geq s\geq a$ for any $a\in A$. It follows that $cb\geq cs\geq ca$ for any $a\in A$. As $b\geq a$ for any $a\in A$, $cb$ is an upper bound for $cA$, and because $b$ is *any* upper bound of $A$, $cs$ is the least upper bound. Therefore, $cs=\sup(cA)$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Is this statement true if $c<0$?

Comment: @ziggurism Forgot to add that $c\geq 0$, my bad.

Comment: I think your final line of thinking is correct. You need to write it carefully though. Show that $s_1/c\geq a$ for all $a$, which you have done. And show that it is also less than any other upper bound, which you have not yet done.

Comment: I think it will look slightly nicer if you start with $s_2$ and multiply by $c$, rather than starting with $s_1$ and dividing by $c$. But that's just because I hate division.

Comment: If I say that $cb_2\geq ca$ for any $a\in A$, can I immediately conclude that $cb_2$ is an arbitrary upper bound to $cA$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ziggurism How is my second proof?

Comment: The inequality $\forall a, cb\geq cs\geq ca$ shows that $cs$ is an upper bound of $cA$, but I feel that you should also say this in words, for a readable proof. That is the result you are proving. Additionally, it is true that every upper bound of $cA$ is of the form $cb,$ where $b$ is any upper bound of $A$, but it may be worth one line to prove this. Finally, it may also be nice to state, in words, the result: $cs$ is also a _least_ upper bound.

Comment: Does that look any better?

Comment: Yes, now it is perfect and lovely.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, what $\sup$ is: (with a little category theory flavour)

---

$\sup(A)$ if it exists, is:

1. an upper bound of $A$
2. so that for every $b$ an upper bound of $A$, we have $\sup(A) \le b$

---

Now we will prove that $c\sup(A)$ is $\sup(cA)$.

1. Let $cx \in cA$ where $x \in A$. Then, $x \le \sup(A)$ by the first property of $\sup$. Therefore, $c \sup(A)$ is an upper bound of $cA$.
2. Let $b$ be another upper bound of $cA$. If $c \ne 0$, then $b/c$ is an upper bound of $A$, so we have $\sup(A) \le b/c$ by the second property of $\sup$, whence $c \sup(A) \le b$. If $c = 0$, then in fact $cA = \{0\}$, and $c \sup(A) = 0$, so if we have $0 \le b$ ($b$ is an upper bound) then it follows that $0 \le b$ ($b$ is greater than or equal to $c \sup(A)$).