# If $c \geq 0 $, show that $\sup(cA)=c\sup A$.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:
"Let $A ⊆ R$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $c ∈ R$.  This time
define the set $cA = \left\{ca : a ∈ A \right\}$. Show that If $c \geq 0$, $\sup(cA)=c\sup A$."

The way I tried to prove this is like the following.

$Proof.$  We know that $\sup A \geq a$ $, \forall a \in A .$ Then for any $c \geq 0$ , $c\sup A \geq ca$. So $c\sup A$ is an upper bound for $cA$. Now since $\sup A \in A$, $c\sup A \in cA$ and $c\sup A \geq ca$, it's clear that $c\sup A$ is the least upper bound for $cA$. Hence  $\sup(cA)=c\sup A$.

Is that the right way to prove it?

Comment: $\sup A$ need not lie in $A$; consider $A=(0,1)$. Then $\sup A = 1$ but $1 \not \in A$. Try arguing using the $\varepsilon$ characterization of supremum.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605384/prove-that-supca-c-supa)

Comment: @Accelerator yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $c>0$. The inequality $\sup (cA) \leqslant c\sup A$ is clear. Let $t$ be such that $ca\leqslant t$ for all $a\in A$. Then $a\leqslant c^{-1}t$ for all $a\in A$ implies $\sup A \leqslant c^{-1}t$. Conclude that $c\sup A= \sup (cA)$.